# Django work flow redirect from one view to another and display page with url parameter

Tags: python, django, parameters, django-views, url-routing

I am trying to create a web app that users will select a file, get data processed and then redirected to a confirmation page with a url parameter(?status=1) How can I move from the processing view to the confirmation view and then display the confirmation page?
   I have put my code below which is not working in my views and urls py files

```
# views.py
def marketdata_processing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploadform = forms.MyUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if uploadform.is_valid():
            newdoc = models.UploadDocument(docfile=request.FILES['uploadfile'])
            filename = request.FILES['uploadfile'].name
            newdoc.save()
            selecteddate = newdoc.getselecteddate()  # Model method calculated
            fileid = newdoc.pk
            request.session['fileid'] = fileid
            request.session['selecteddate'] = selecteddate
            return redirect(reverse('views.confirm_input_details'))
    else:
        uploadform = forms.MyUploadForm()
   # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'mytemplate.html',
        {'uploadform': uploadform},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )


def confirm_input_details(request):
    fileid = request.session['fileid']
    selecteddate = request.session['selecteddate']
    msg = 'Proceed to import data for %s? \nFileID Being Imported is %s ' % (
        selecteddate, fileid,)
    url = reverse('views.confirm_input_details', kwargs={'status': 1})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.marketdata_processing, name='myapp/mytemplate.html'),
    url(r'^\?status=(?P<status>[0-9]+)$',
        views.confirm_input_details, name='myapp/myconfirmpage.html'),
]
```

Comment: Do you have an error message? Please post that.

Comment: kindly display the errors you get when you run the code a

Comment: Hi, no error is being displayed, the template is simply loaded without redirecting to the confirm_inputs view at all. The page loads with the url "127.0.0.1/myapp?status=1. I would like the confirm_input view to be called and then the template be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues I feel exist in your code:

- Indentation is a very important thing in python code. Please make sure the indentation of your if-else statements in the 'marketdata_processing' view are in correct order. Beware, in your code:

  ```
  return render_to_response('mytemplate.html',
                           {'uploadform': uploadform},
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```

  will always get executed as it is outside the else statement. You might want to indent it under the else (if it makes sense)- like so:

  ```
  else:
      uploadform = forms.MyUploadForm()
      return render_to_response('mytemplate.html',
                               {'uploadform': uploadform},
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```
- Instead of 'redirect(reverse())' try 'HttpResponseRedirect()' in the processing view to call the confirm-page view, like so:

  ```
  from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

  return HttpResponseRedirect('/?status=1')       --> relative URL shown
  ```

  place the relative/absolute url (both would work) above.
- Finally, render your confirm-page template in the 'confirm_input_details' view with the context parameters, like so:

  ```
     def confirm_input_details(request):
         fileid = request.session['fileid']
         selecteddate = request.session['selecteddate']
         msg = 'Proceed to import data for %s? \nFileID Being Imported is %s ' % (selecteddate, fileid)

         return render_to_response('confirmpage_template.html'),
                                  {'fileid': fileid,
                                   'selecteddate': selecteddate,
                                   'msg': msg}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```

** P.S: Stick to neat basics and it will work. You happened to call your confirm_input_details view from within the same view itself. As far as I think, that would probably take you into an infinite loop. Simple concept of any view is:

```
    take input:request, parameters 
     --> process logic with parameters 
      --> render a specific template or call another url where a template is being rendered.
```

You can't expect a page to show up without the rendering a template.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer it has made everything so much clearer. I have been using code snippets, I think from different versions of Django. I have redesigned the whole app. The code is much simpler and clearer. This problem has been sorted out.